# hook action order grid not work in prestashop 1.7

Tags: hook, prestashop-1.7

On my custom module i followed [this documentation steps](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/sample-modules/grid-and-identifiable-object-form-hooks-usage/) for add columns on customer grid, it works, so i tried to replicate for the order grid but nothing happens.
Prestashop version: 1.7.6.7

```php
  public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            ...
            $this->registerHook('actionOrderGridDefinitionModifier') &&   \\ this not works
            $this->registerHook('actionCustomerGridDefinitionModifier') && \\ this works
           ...
    }



    public function hookActionCustomerGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function hookActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order page (back office) isn't migrated yet to the new framework (Symfony) in the 1.7.6.x, it has been migrated in the 1.7.7, so it's normal that that hooks doesn't works :)

For all the others page, already migrated to Symfony the hooks will work.

Here you'll find the 1.7.7 kanban projects to follow the progress: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/projects/7